# How to update label based on change event of its sibling select using class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to use many select element with same options.I've to add a on chage event listener that will listen any change in these similar selects.But I want to udate only the the label that is the actual sibling of the select that is actually changed its option using class selector not id.Somehow, i figure out the id of the select that actually changed its option.However, on change event is updating both the labels.Its too tricky to me.remember that i am going to use too many  selects with same event listen.so i cant use id selector.Please help.

```js
$('.p-select').on('change', function() {
   //alert(this.id);
  var eid = "#"+this.id+"";
  alert('eid: '+eid);  
  $(eid).siblings(".p-label").html($(".p-select option:selected").text());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="p-label"></label>
<select class='p-select' id="s1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>

<div>
<label class="p-label"></label>  
<select class='p-select' id="s2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use current element context i.e. `this`, when getting the `selected` option's text as well as selecting `.sibling()` element.

```
$('.p-select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).siblings(".p-label").html($("option:selected", this).text());
    //$(this).prev(".p-label").html($("option:selected", this).text());    
    //$(this).closest('div').find(".p-label").html($("option:selected", this).text()); 
});
```

```js
$('.p-select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings(".p-label").html($("option:selected", this).text());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="p-label"></label>
<select class='p-select' id="s1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>

<div>
<label class="p-label"></label>  
<select class='p-select' id="s2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following solution:

```js
$('.p-select').on('change', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var newLabel = that.find('option:selected').text();
   that.closest('div').children('label').html(newLabel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="p-label"></label>
<select class='p-select' id="s1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>

<div>
<label class="p-label"></label>  
<select class='p-select' id="s2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` also

```
$('.p-select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest(".p-label").html($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```